# How can I translate the FileNet ID ID in DB2/Oracle into friendly GUID?

Tags: sql, oracle, db2, guid, filenet-content-engine

The IBM Technote "[How to translate the unique identifier as displayed within FileNet Enterprise Manager so that it matches what is stored in the Oracle and DB2 databases](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21587420)" outlines how DB2 & Oracle store guids in a byte reversed order. How can I convert them into a friendly guid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does the trick in DB2, following the recipe from the IBM Technote:

```
‘{’ concat  upper(VARCHAR_FORMAT_BIT(
 cast(substring(F.Object_id, 4, 1) concat
 substring(F.Object_id, 3, 1) concat
 substring(F.Object_id, 2, 1)  concat
 substring(F.Object_id, 1, 1)  concat
 substring(F.Object_id, 6, 1)  concat
 substring(F.Object_id, 5, 1)  concat
 substring(F.Object_id, 8, 1)  concat
 substring(F.Object_id, 7, 1)  concat
 substring(F.Object_id, 9) as char(16)), ‘xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx’)) concat ‘}’ as object_id
```

The "cast as char(16)" is a gotcha - casting to varchar(16) does not work on DB2 at least.

Here's the before and after:

[image: guids]

Answer (score 3):

Presuming that object_id is `char(16) for bit data`, the following expression returns the same.

```
'{'||translate(
  'GHEFCDAB-KLIJ-OPMN-QRST-UVWXYZ012345'
, hex(F.object_id)
, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012345')||'}' as object_id
```

Comment: I was hoping to mark this as the accepted answer, but it's a varchar(16) for bit data, so this solution doesn't work.

Comment: It does work on varchar(16) for bit data as well. Try this: `select '{'||translate(
  'GHEFCDAB-KLIJ-OPMN-QRST-UVWXYZ012345'
, hex(F.object_id)
, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012345')||'}' as object_id
, hex(F.object_id)                         as original_object_id
from table( values 
  cast(x'6640864000001eccb61ceaaa453b3870' as varchar(16) for bit data)
, cast(x'66460680000015c39fc48c928e241e3b' as varchar(16) for bit data)
) F (object_id)`. If it doesn't work for you, then what's your db2 platform and version?