# Fetch absolute or relative path using file object in IBM filenet

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

```
String mySQLString = "select * from document where documentTitle like '%test%' ";
SearchSQL sql = new SearchSQL(mySQLString);
IndependentObjectSet s = search.fetchObjects(sql, 10, null, true);
Document doc;
PageIterator iterator = s.pageIterator();
iterator.nextPage();

for (Object object : iterator.getCurrentPage()) {
    doc = (Document) object;
    Properties properties = doc.getProperties();
    //I am trying to get an absolute or relative path here for every document.
    // for eg: /objectstorename/foldername/filename like this.
}
```

I have tried searching propeties and class descriptions in document . but can't able to find the path. ?

Comment: There is no such thing as "path of a document". Document can be filed in multiple folders or could not be filed at all. You shoud examine corresponding `ReferentialContainmentRelationship` objects.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [FoldersFiledIn](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.5.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.prop.doc/props_Versionable.htm#FoldersFiledIn) property and accompanying [get_FoldersFiledIn()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.5.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.java.doc/com/filenet/api/core/Versionable.html#get_FoldersFiledIn--) method.

Answer (score 4):

To do it all in one single query (as you are trying to do in your code) you can create a join with the `ReferentialContainmentRelationship` table. The property `Head` of this table points to the document, the property `Tail` points to the folder the document is filled in and the property `ContainmentName` is the name the document has in the folder. Use the following code to construct the document path:

```java
SearchSQL searchSQL = new SearchSQL("SELECT R.ContainmentName, R.Tail, D.This FROM Document AS D WITH INCLUDESUBCLASSES INNER JOIN ReferentialContainmentRelationship AS R WITH INCLUDESUBCLASSES ON D.This = R.Head WHERE DocumentTitle like '%test%'");
SearchScope searchScope = new SearchScope(objectStore);
RepositoryRowSet objects = searchScope.fetchRows(searchSQL, null, null, null);
Iterator<RepositoryRow> iterator = objects.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    RepositoryRow repositoryRow = iterator.next();
    Properties properties = repositoryRow.getProperties();
    Folder folder = (Folder) properties.get("Tail").getEngineObjectValue();
    String containmentName = properties.get("ContainmentName").getStringValue();

    System.out.println(folder.get_PathName() + "/" + containmentName);
}
```

Paths constructed this way can also be used to fetch the object from the object store. The query code can be optimized by using a property filter as the third argument of the `fetchRows()` method. Don't know how this behaves if the document is filed in multiple folders.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you explore the "Creating DynamicReferentialContainmentRelationship Objects" section of FileNet documentation:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.5.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/containment_procedures.htm#containment_procedures__fldr_creating_a_drcr

A FileNet Ddocument can be assigned to multiple Folders, so you can have several logical "Paths" for a given document.

At end, you should get something like "Folder.get_PathName() + DynamicReferentialContainmentRelationship.get_Name()" to display the full pathname.

As described by samples in FileNet documentation, a relationship object (e.g. DynamicReferentialContainmentRelationship) controls the relation of document/folder:

myRelationshipObject.set_Head(myDocument);

myRelationshipObject.set_Tail(myFolder);

Also, keep in mind that a FileNet Document can be also a "unfiled" document, so there is no actual "pathname" or folder "relationship" to be retrieved.

Answer (score -1):

tl;dr from [FileNet Content Engine - Database Table for Physical path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31984971/9602361)

> Documents are stored among the directories at the leaf level using a hashing algorithm to evenly distribute files among these leaf directories.